# Is there a way to automate the generation of test data for MongoDB

Tags: java, testing, mongodb, morphia

I have a DTO being mapped to MongoDB using morphia. Is there any way of generating randomised test data for MongoDB (as per my DTO) without writing something in-house?

Comment: Note that this is acceptance testing, not unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll either have to generate test data by generating mongoimport compatible files or through Morphia (preferred) with some of your own code.

Comment: I guess there is no way to upload a file to GridFS and reference that file in the imported data without manual intervention? Looks like a small utility will better suit my needs.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. Good luck.